# jQuery slideshow with images from mysql db

Tags: jquery, mysql

My slideshow works only if I put code like this, and it doesn't display first picture.

```
<--db connection-->
echo "
<div id='con'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {



    echo "<div>";

    echo "<a href = 'results.php?query=$row[object]&boc=option0'><img src ='send/$row[photo]'></a>";
    echo "<a class = \"ob\" href = 'results.php?query=$row[object]&boc=option0'>$row[object]</a>";
    echo "</div>";

echo "</div>";


}
}

  ?>
```

If I change location of div 'con', like it (in my opinion) should look,

```
echo "
<div id='con'>";    

if ($result) {

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {



    echo "<div>";

    echo "<a href = 'results.php?query=$row[obiekt]&boc=option0'><img src ='send/$row[photo]'></a>";
    echo "<a class = \"ob\" href = 'results.php?query=$row[obiekt]&boc=option0'>$row[obiekt]</a>";
    echo "</div>";




}



}
 echo "</div>";
```

my file is displayed properly only if I write its URL, and enter the site.
And I want to load this file into div of another site. And it works only with first example code, and without first image as i wrote.

I add these code to main site by this  :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#con").load('json.php');
});
```

And this how I make this sildeshow

```
$("#con > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
$('#con > div:first')
.fadeOut(1000)
.next()
.fadeIn(1000)
.end()
.appendTo('#con');
 },  3000);
```

What do I do wrong ?

Comment: create Fiddle for your problem please http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Tryed to make fiddle but there's no php or mysql options, or I couldn't find it. And also  I can write only one file there and I need at least two to make my project work.

Comment: here' s what I've done , but I don't think it will help to find solution. http://jsfiddle.net/6RY6j/

Comment: Ok I fixed it, the reson why it doesn't work was funny: same name of div in both files, should be other in one of them.